# SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column

Tags: laravel, postgresql

even if I add protected $primaryKey = 'TEA_ID' in the model am getting this error , am using postgres as database
my migration:

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('T_TEAM_TEA', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('TEA_ID');
            $table->integer('TEA_MANAGER') ;  
            $table->string('TEA_NAME'); 
            $table->string('TEA_DESCRIPTION'); 
            $table->integer('TEA_SITE') ; 
            $table->timestamps();
           
        });
    }

my model : 

  /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'T_TEAM_TEA';
    /**
     * Protected var for acronym
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $acronym = 'TEA';
   

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $primaryKey = 'TEA_ID';
     

     /**
     * Mass assignement
     *
     * @var array
     */
   

     /**
     * Relation for site table
     *
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Site::class,
            (new Site)->getKeyName(),
            $this->acronym . '_SITE'
        );
    }

     /**
     * Relation for user table
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            User::class,
            (new User)->getAcronym() . '_TEAM',
            $this->primaryKey
        );
    }




      /**
     * Get Acronym
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAcronym()
    {
        return $this->acronym;
    }
```

Comment: you can also do it like this

$table->increments('TEA_ID')->primary();

Comment: can you share your controller code where do you facing the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

mistake in this

```
public $primaryKey = 'TEA_ID';
```

fix like this.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'TEA_ID';
```

Comment: even if i put protected instead of public i got the same error

Comment: Please explain where this error occurs

Comment: this error occures when i try to insert data in postgres database

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data or any important data so far in the database you can remigrate freshly by this command

php artisan migrate:fresh

this will remigrate everything since everytime you do a change you migrate in your migrations table. The change won't be affected unless this table has reflected changes...